# Tmux doesn't show line breaks when calling `shell` to display output from Bash command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tmux

Given the following text file "HelloWorld.txt"

> Hello World
>
> ~~~line break~~~
>
> This is a text file

In .tmux.conf, I config the following setup:

```
bind F1 shell "cat HelloWorld.txt"
```

When I use this shortcut, Tmux prints the following:

> Hello World
>
> This is a text file

That line break just disappears mysteriously.

How can I preserve line breaks?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "line break"? Also, `shell` is not a valid `tmux` command; did you mean `run-shell`?

Comment: 1/ `shell` is an alias for `run-shell`. 2/ By "line break", I mean a blank line.

Comment: `run` is an alias for `run-shell`. Other than that, the behavior seems to be a known issue (see [workaround](https://github.com/davejamesmiller/dotfiles/blob/e4c65c6dc9c9b4692961bb6d3d8cfd894f45cb84/.tmux.conf#L61)).

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a bug report but this seems to be how tmux' `run-shell` command behaves. The [workaround I found](https://github.com/davejamesmiller/dotfiles/blob/e4c65c6dc9c9b4692961bb6d3d8cfd894f45cb84/.tmux.conf#L61) is to pipe the output via `sed` to replace each blank line with a space.

Your example would then become like this:

```
bind F1 run-shell "cat HelloWorld.txt | sed 's/^$/ /'"
```